# Mount drive rw in fstab

Tags: linux, debian

I have a Proxmox server with 4 external drives, one internal ssd and one internal hdd (containing the os) attached to my server.

I edited the /etc/fstab file so the drives are mounted when the server is powered on. However when the server is powered on the drives are mounted read-only, even though I use rw in the fstab file. Does any one know how I need to solve this??

/etc/fstab

```
# <file system>         <mount point>   <type>  <options>                               <dump>  <pass>
/dev/pve/root           /               ext4    errors=remount-ro                       0       1
UUID=C479-3467          /boot/efi       vfat    defaults                                0       1
/dev/pve/swap           none            swap    sw                                      0       0
proc                    /proc           proc    defaults                                0       0

# Samba
# Western Digital 2TB
UUID=38EC96E9EC96A124   /mnt/backup     ntfs    rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,nouser,async      0       2
# HGST 1TB 7200rpm
UUID=ACFE5A96FE5A58A2   /mnt/files      ntfs    rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,nouser,async      0       2
# Seagate 4TB
UUID=E4E86DFDE86DCE7C   /mnt/movies     ntfs    rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,nouser,async      0       2
# HGST 1TB 5400rpm
UUID=C6F0C056F0C04E7D   /mnt/pictures   ntfs    rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,nouser,async      0       2

# Git
# Kingston 128GB
UUID=A664F83764F80BB5   /mnt/git        ntfs    rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,nouser,async      0       2
```

On the bottom of the /proc/self/mounts file you can see that the drives are mounted read-only (ro)

```
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=2038174,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,size=3267128k,mode=755 0 0
/dev/dm-0 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
tmpfs /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd 0 0
pstore /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/memory cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/pids cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids 0 0
systemd-1 /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc autofs rw,relatime,fd=21,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct 0 0
mqueue /dev/mqueue mqueue rw,relatime 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
hugetlbfs /dev/hugepages hugetlbfs rw,relatime 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /mnt/git ntfs ro,relatime,uid=0,gid=0,fmask=0177,dmask=077,nls=utf8,errors=continue,mft_zone_multiplier=1 0 0
/dev/sdf1 /mnt/backup ntfs ro,relatime,uid=0,gid=0,umask=00,nls=utf8,errors=continue,mft_zone_multiplier=1 0 0
/dev/sdc2 /mnt/movies ntfs ro,relatime,uid=0,gid=0,fmask=0177,dmask=077,nls=utf8,errors=continue,mft_zone_multiplier=1 0 0
/dev/sdd1 /mnt/pictures ntfs ro,relatime,uid=0,gid=0,fmask=0177,dmask=077,nls=utf8,errors=continue,mft_zone_multiplier=1 0 0
/dev/sde1 /mnt/files ntfs ro,relatime,uid=0,gid=0,fmask=0177,dmask=077,nls=utf8,errors=continue,mft_zone_multiplier=1 0 0
/dev/sda2 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
rpc_pipefs /run/rpc_pipefs rpc_pipefs rw,relatime 0 0
lxcfs /var/lib/lxcfs fuse.lxcfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other 0 0
/dev/fuse /etc/pve fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
```

And my syslog when I powered on the server:
https://pastebin.com/GiA9T2Ue

Comment: Guess: The NTFS kernel driver found the filesystems in a state that it can read, but can't write, because compared to Windows the NTFS driver is still not complete. If you are using these drives exclusively on the Server, I strongly recommend to switch to a different filesystem that's more suitable for Linux.

Comment: Strongly agree with dirkt. Use a native filesystem unless you have a compelling reason to do otherwise. Other possibilities: 1. Check those filesystems for errors (might have to boot with Win to do that - I dunno). 2. Take them out of fstab and mount them with a script after boot.

Comment: I changed the filesystem to ext4 and I was able to write on them, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the filesystem to ext4 and I was able to write on them.